# Android activity error 5

Tags: android, android-activity

Good day for all the guru's of developing here, first of all, sorry for my bad english but I have an error in a Android app that I'am developing and I couldn`t fix it, and I google it and don't find any answer.

**The logcat**

```
09-28 13:21:59.360    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-28 13:21:59.360    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
09-28 13:21:59.362    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
09-28 13:21:59.384    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app-2/lib/x86
09-28 13:21:59.387    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-28 13:21:59.387    2085-2085/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app, PID: 2085
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app/com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app.PrincipalActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2090)
            at com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app.PrincipalActivity.<init>(PrincipalActivity.java:22)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-28 13:22:01.785    2085-2085/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2085 SIG: 9
```

**PrincipalActivity.java**

```
package com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText EdtxtCedula=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblCedula);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        Button btnAceptar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnAceptar);

        btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean existeDocumento;
                existeDocumento = conection();
                validacionDocumento(existeDocumento);
            }


        });
    }

    private void validacionDocumento(boolean validar) {
        if (validar==true){
            Intent intent = new Intent(PrincipalActivity.this, ProfesionalActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("CEDULA", Integer.parseInt(EdtxtCedula.getText().toString()));
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            EdtxtCedula.setText("");
        }
    }

    private boolean conection() {
        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://";
        final String user = "";
        final String pass = "";
        boolean resultadoConexion = false;
        TextView lblCambio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblBienvenido);
        try{

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from usuarios where id="+EdtxtCedula.getText());
            //ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            //rs.next();
            //lblCambio.setText(rs.getString(1));
            while (rs.next()){
                if ( rs.getRow() == 0 )
                {
                    //es un result set vacío
                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "La cedula no existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     toast.show();
                     resultadoConexion = false;

                }else{
                    //el result set tiene datos
                        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conexion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        //toast.show();
                        lblCambio.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        resultadoConexion = true;
                }
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultadoConexion;
    }


}
```

**activity_principal.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:id="@+id/layContenedor"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".PrincipalActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/colpsic_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="354dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_descripcion">
    </ImageView>

    <RelativeLayout   android:id="@+id/layTexto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp">

        <TextView  android:id="@+id/lblBienvenido"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/bienvenido"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textColor="#0107ff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView   android:id="@+id/lblMensaje_Bienvenida"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/mensaje"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#2514ff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblBienvenido"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/lblCedula"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/cedula"
            android:textColorHint="#CFCFCF"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblMensaje_Bienvenida"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BarraBotones"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnAceptar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Aceptar"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnCancelar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/salir"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifiest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.colpsic.domain.colpsic_app" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PrincipalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfesionalActivity"
            android:label="Profesional" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you say what you've tried to resolve the issue yourself? Maybe add some narration about what happens, not just an uncommented stack trace. Just to help people understand what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line needs to go inside of a method. (in this case, `onCreate`)

```
EditText EdtxtCedula=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblCedula);
```

It crashes because by the time this line is called, `setContentView` has not been called for the activity, so it doesn't know where to find your `EditText`

Put it with your other views, like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    Button btnAceptar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnAceptar);
    EditText EdtxtCedula=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblCedula);

    btnAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean existeDocumento;
            existeDocumento = conection();
            validacionDocumento(existeDocumento);
        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove this `EditText EdtxtCedula=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblCedula);` from `PrincipalActivity` and put it into `onCreate` method

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        Button btnAceptar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnAceptar);
        EditText EdtxtCedula=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lblCedula);
```